# Vala - Bytes convert to string?

Tags: string, byte, vala

I have a **GLib.Bytes** object.

I want to print it and use it as a **string** like this:

```cs
Bytes bytes = new Bytes({65, 66, 67});

print(bytes); // <-- ERROR
```

How can I convert it to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get **raw byte array** `uint8[]` with [Bytes.get_data()](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Bytes.get_data.html) and **cast** it as string.

Example:

```cs
Bytes bytes = new Bytes({65, 66, 67});

string str = (string)bytes.get_data();
print(str);
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

Comment: Careful - this won't work if bytes object lacks a null terminator, which it very well might.